# Convert JSON String Storing LatLng values to Java Array

Tags: java, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with understanding what I am doing wrong here:

I'm connected to a mongodb database via mongoose, and have filtered so that only the coordinates are relayed back.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
                            Location.find({'email':email},{coordinates: 1 , _id: 0}).lean().exec(function (err, locations) {
                                const points = JSON.stringify(locations);
                                //const coords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locations));
                                console.log(points);
                                res.send(points);
                                //res.json(points);
                            })
```

The result looks something like this:

```
[{"coordinates":["lat/lng: (49.47866007286142,-1.2380338609218597)","lat/lng: (57.47785037139205,-1.2392844408750534)"]}]
```

However when I attempt to parse into an array in Java with:

```
compositeDisposable.add(service.getLocations()
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void accept(String res) throws Exception {
                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                                            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                                            {
                                                JSONObject coord = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                            }

                                        }
```

I get the error: of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

What would be a more appropriate way to parse this into a LatLng array so that I can loop through it and display on my map?

Comment: _"The result looks something like this: `[{"coordinates"...`"_ - The top level object is a JSONArray (notice the initial `[`).  I'm not enough of an expert to tell you exactly how to fix this, but where you have `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);` it should be `JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(res);`

Comment: JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(res);
                                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                                            {
                                                JSONObject coord = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                                System.out.println(coord);
                                            }
Ah I see, I've changed it to this. This still prints the array as a whole rather than splitting it?

Comment: @Jonwil It is a string in your JSON - how would you expect it to know what to do beyond that?  If you changed - `"lat/lng: (49.47866007286142,-1.2380338609218597)"` to ```{ "lat":49.47866, "long":-1.238033
}``` then it could be decoded by the JSON framework..